# SVG animation leaves banding artifacts in Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95

Tags: google-chrome, animation, svg, gpu, visual-artifacts

While testing an SVG animation I've run into a rendering problem in Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95.

The animated triangles seem to leave some black vertical banding.
This goes away if you tab away from the page and back or if you otherwise force a redraw.

You can find the animation test here:
http://bit.ly/HexaGridTest

And here's a screenshot:
[image]

Looking at other posts on similar issues it seems that the only way to eliminate this GPU-acceleration-related problem is to force a redraw at the end of the animation.

Someone suggested adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the SVG, but this didn't solve the issue for me.

Is there any alternative? Any flag or CSS property I could set to avoid the artifacts?

Comment: Try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to a parent div (must be created) instead of the SVG itself.

Comment: Updated the test with the CSS you suggested, but to no avail.

Comment: Feel free to update the question with a link to a webkit/chromium bugreport.